# IIS 2019: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis, windows-server-2019

I've seen others post similar issues and go down the route of using the following code snippet

```
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
```

However, I'm still having issues with the following scenario.

I have a Web App running on IIS on Windows Server (An EC2 Instance Win 2019 Server) and a Microservice running on Kestrel.  If I RDP to the Win Server and open up Chrome/Firefox/Edge I can navigate to the micro-service, make a basic API call and see data come back.   However, when the IIS application tries to access the the API I get the following error in my logs

> ```
>       InnerException:
> ```

```
        >       Type:       HttpRequestException
        >       Message:    An error occurred while sending the request.
        >       Data:       0 entries
        >       Stack trace:
```

> ```
>               ----------------
>               InnerException:
>
>                       Type:       WebException
>                       Message:    The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure >channel.
>                       Data:       0 entries
>                       Stack trace:
> ```

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
                        InnerException is null
```

The certificate is valid/trusted/secured.  So there's no issue there.

I'm assuming that when the request goes from the Web App in IIS and tries to reach out to the API, it doesn't like something?   Is there a way to get further info on why I'm getting the exception(s)

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to analyze TLS handshake packets and then the cause should be clear.

Comment: If you make request locally I assume it works, but when trying to test outside is that when you are having issue?

Comment: Yup, I left an answer below.  IT appears it's due to how TLS 1.2 works in IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was the answer
https://trailheadtechnology.com/solving-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-error-in-net-4-6-x/

I hope this saves someone some time and headaches

Comment: Please provide the relevant information in your answer instead of just linking to some external site.